# What programming languages are most 'hire-able'?

Tags: software-industry, job-search

If I'm interested in having the most employment opportunities possible available to me, which 5 programming languages should I learn? I'm interested in possibly working for larger corporate firms as well as would like to potentially work for smaller companies and start-ups. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Julie, welcome to The Workplace SE! This is an interesting question, but I added a post notice explaining to answerers that they should be sure to provide good explanations that explain why and how. It looks like you already got a good answer so far. Good luck! :)

Comment: I think the answers will be primary opinion-based. Most people will probably recommend the language which is or was most useful for them.

Comment: i don't think this is really opinion-based. There are perfectly reasonable arguments you can make for a "most hireable" language, and there is, emperically, a language out there that has the most people working on it

Comment: I think this question can be answered by looking at certain statistics. For example: http://www.wantedanalytics.com/insight/2013/04/27/update-on-the-most-in-demand-programming-languages/

Comment: @bharal - This is a list question.  Unfortunately we are limited in our choices for close reasons still so list questions fall into the opinion bucket... yeah change!

Comment: Javascript is it , then jQuery, then CSS, then HTML, then some mo' Javascript. I would say Java .. but hmm, javaSCRIPT!

Comment: Whatever the answer is now, it'll be a different group of languages in a year, if not in six months. And you'll constantly have to learn more.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript.

All corporates have a front-facing website, and javascript is also making a big appearance on server-side technologies as well.

Almost every startup is also going to have a website too, plus you can use javascript to develop web apps, mobile apps and you can use it for server-side databases and the like, which will be attractive to a startup to use.

Note that I don't mean "just" javascript, but rather javascript, jQuery, underscore, backbone and javascript unit testing of some sort.

Otherwise, you could do worse than learning C# or Java.

However, by your question you're sounding like you don't have a degree (otherwise you'd probably know a language or two) ~ unless you're planning on getting one, getting a corporate gig is going to take you a *long* time. Like, years long, not weeks or months. You would need several non-corporate gigs to get your first corporate one. Startups/smaller companies are the way to go, in which case my original advice on javascript becomes even more relevant. Without a degree i wouldn't bother learning Java, C# or, to a lesser extent, Python.

Also, 5 languages is a *lot*. Try one at first!

Comment: All corporates may have a public website, but not all of them build/maintain that website. Many contract it out to another company, and just add/update content via a CMS with no employees ever touching the site code or even the server.

Comment: Thanks @bharal! I'm putting a recommendation together for a college that is looking to develop a curriculum for entry-level developers. It would be a 6-month, full-time, post-secondary program that is meant to be nowhere close to as in-depth as a degree, but give the students enough employable skills to launch their careers.

Comment: You'll be hard pressed to teach 5 languages in 6 months. You'd be lucky to get people half-way competent in 1 in 6 months.

Comment: @Rubinator oh i see what you're getting at. In that case I would recommend a focus html&css& some basic jQuery/javascript still OR maybe html&css&php - but you are, as Lego Stormtroopr noticed, going to be V.hard placed to teach much of anything in that time frame.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr - If someone is determined, they could grok Javascript in 6. VERY DETERMINEd!

Answer (score 2):

One thing neglected in all this is SQL. Someone working on big corporate projects should be able to create sophisticated stored procedures.

Supposedly Java is the most highly used language due to it's simultaneous use on a lot of corporate web systems as well as for Android.  JavaScript is absolutely important, however it isn't a very good place to start - there is a lot of 'stuff' and some of it deviates from what one is commonly used to in programming, such as in particular weak typing.

The place to start is one of three 'language pairs':

- Visual Basic for Applications (VBA)/Microsoft Access and T/SQL (SQL
  Server)
- Java and PL/SQL (Oracle)
- C# and T/SQL (Microsoft Visual Studio and SQL Server)

All of these are 'Winforms', i.e., not HTML/CSS based. This is another ball of wax. Doing console and forms stuff first gets you some idea of what the controls collections do, before starting to get mixed up in the nuances of HTML, XHTML, DHTML, CSS, etc.  Once you can make 'round trips' getting data into and out of an SQL database then it makes sense to focus on the web side.

If you need to earn a living in a hurry, Access is the best place to start.  Access applications are 'can openers' - the kind of job rank beginners can be useful at.

Comment: I would like to know why this is downvoted?

Comment: @Meredith_Poor thank you! The idea of language pairings is a new one. Definitely worth a consideration.

Answer (score 2):

If there would be 5 "most-hireable" programming languages, everybody would learn them, right? Because it would make no sense to learn any other programming language at all.

The problem is that there are so many fields in programming that 5 programming languages do not fit them all. I would recommend to look at it from an other perspective:

**What do I want to develop and which programming languages do I need for it?**

Do you want to make websites? Mobile apps? Desktop applications? Databases? Software for machines?

Then take a look at some job offers which match your preferences. You may see that in web development, HTML, Javascript, CSS, Java and C# is needed. Sometimes you need also some Database (SQL) knowledge.

Based on that, you can start to learn.

But, be aware that in every software development job you will have to learn something new. In the end, you need to get a job done. And also, if you are working primary in Java, and suddenly you need to do some SQL, you will learn it because you will need it.

Comment: um, no. There are *plenty* of people using oblique languages earning packets of money who have no interest in mixing with the hoi-polloi. There are also plenty of people wanting to  challenge themselves, or work on  specalist products etc who won't want the most hireable skills.

Comment: @bharal I do not really understand what relation your comment has to my answer. Could you please explain?

Comment: assuming you're following the conventino of leading with your thesis: my disagreement is utterly with "If there would be 5 "most-hireable" programming languages, everybody would learn them, right?" Also, sometimes people want to learn something just for a steady job, not because they have a love of bits